# Regex python positive multiline lookahead fro specific string

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I've been looking through this on regex101 and SO but can't quite figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have a multiline string like:

```
23. 
     Martin K, Thompson KG, Keegan R, Ball N, Rattray B. Mental fatigue does not mid:25425259. 
                  View Article
```

and I want to extract everything between the `23.` and the `"View Article"` string.

This regex (multiline enabled):

```
\d{1,2}.([^?V]*)
```

does the job but fails if `V` is in the string itself before it occurs in `View...`.

In other words, I think I am looking for a positive multiline lookahead until `"View Article"`.

Here's a demo of what I've been doing: [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/rH9bC3/1)

Comment: Just `(?s)\d{1,2}\.(.*?)View Article` should be enough.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. What does the `(?s)` do?

Comment: ***s modifier:** single line. Dot matches newline characters*

Comment: The `(?s)` is an inline DOTALL modifier.